# PowerShellでLPRコマンドでPDF印刷をするときにサイズを指定したい

Tags: windows, powershell

LinuxでLPRで印刷するときには-o media=A5とつければA5で印刷することができましたがWindows（PowerShell）では同じオプションでは同じように動作してくれません。
デバイス設定のプリンタ設定で既定サイズを変更しても無視してA4で印刷されてしまいます。
何かサイズを指定してLPRでPDF印刷する方法はないでしょうか？

LPRが使いたいというよりアプリのインストールなしでPDFをコマンドラインからサイズ指定をして印刷がしたいので、別解でも良いので教えてほしいです。

Comment: おそらくPowerShellかどうかには関係無く、cmd.exeでも使えるWindowsの[lprコマンド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/lpr)にはそのような標準化された機能は無さそうです。もしかしたら`-d`パラメータで何かのデータファイルを送信することで実現できるかもしれませんが、それはプリンタの機種に非常に依存した対策になりそうです。LPRでなければこんな記事が参考になりそうです。[PowerShellを使って既定のプリンターの変更と用紙設定の変更](https://qiita.com/arachan@github/items/438f4cd806d445aa8ce5) あるいはWSL/WSL2のLinuxから印刷してみるとか？

Comment: 類似のアイデアとして、MinGW, MSYS2, CygWinなどにUnix互換のLPRコマンドはあるのでしょうか？ それらがあるなら試してみては？

Answer (score 0):

```sh
Get-Printer | Set-PrintConfiguration -PaperSize A5
```

みたいに設定した後で、lprを実行すればできるんじゃないですかね。

参考: https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/printmanagement/set-printconfiguration?view=windowsserver2022-ps